# Google+ page and Google+ local page for a business cound as duplicate listings?

Tags: google, local-seo, google-plus, google-local-search

I've got a Google+ page for a business; this business also has a Google+ local page (Google Places). I was wondering if this was hindering our local SEO efforts by giving us duplicate listings?

Does any one have any experience of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not since Google allows it and you can manage multiple accounts from one Google+ account both business and personal. Google places migrated to Google plus not too long ago. Have you searched Google specifically to see which of the pages is linked to Google maps in search results? Whichever is showing up in map listings (local listings) at the top of the search results I would focus my attention to that page.

Comment: thanks, thats the same conclusion i came to, but for saftys sake i deleted the google+ page and just left my google+ local page so there would be no confusion